# How can I point to data in a file?

Tags: c++, pointers, compression, memory-address

So, I've been trying to understand compression for a while, read some articles, watched some videos and the video with the best explanation said that you need to make data point to identical data. I didn't understand this part very good. I have good knowledge of pointers and how they work, but I still don't understand how I can "point to data in a file". Can anyone help me understand that and how I can do it, if it's very advanced then a book or article that explains it would be enough.

Comment: I don't think "you need to make data point to identical data" makes much sense at all, and have no idea what they mean. I'm sure there are better explanations available, but possibly not in a video.

Comment: If anybody knows other good resources then please share it with me.

Comment: You can save the file position of the data in the file.  When you need the data, position to that location and read the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file is an "array" of bytes. While you cannot have a pointer to this array, you can use the other form of referring to an array element: The index. That is, if the data begins on the third byte of file, then all that you need to locate the data is the name of the file and index of the byte which is 2.

Comment: I don't quite understand this last part: "The index. That is, if the data begins on the third byte of file, then all that you need to locate the data is the name of the file and index of the byte which is 2."
Could you elaborate please?

Comment: A "file" may contain more than an array of bytes, including attributes, NTFS streams in Windows, handles, compression info etc. Your answer implies that he has read everything into memory and assuming that it's an array of bytes, which is not always the case.

Comment: @BilyDev You store the number of the byte in the file. If it's the 3rd byte then you store the number 3. Or 2 if you start counting from 0.

Comment: @user253751 Ah, thanks. And how does that help me with compression?

Comment: @BilyDev Hopefully the numbers 400 and 1200 (for example) are smaller than the 1200 bytes starting at byte number 400.

Comment: @user253751 Ohhh, and de-compression will be the opposite, right? And of course we need to check if the bytes are bigger than the data

Comment: @BilyDev Yes, if it takes 8 bytes to store the position and the size of the data, then you don't want to store 8 bytes to save only 6 bytes of data, because that makes the file bigger.

Comment: @BilyDev *real* compression algorithms use lots of tricks to store these numbers with the smallest possible number of bits. I suggest you research them.

Comment: @user253751 Alright thank you, I'll do more research about compression.